# How to reshape inputs for LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I input a feature after some processing (inside the neural network) into an LSTM. The LSTM has only one "timestep", I reshape the data to input it to the LSTM but get an error saying that I have a 4D tensor instead of 3D.

I do not understand. How to do this design properly?

```
def multiply(x):
    return  tf.keras.layers.multiply(
        [tf.slice(x, [0, 0], [1, -1]), tf.slice(x, [1, 0], [1, -1])]
    )

return_inputs = Input(shape=(2, ))
returns = multiply(return_inputs)
filtered_return = Dense(units=1, activation='relu')(returns)

lstm_returns = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 1, 1), input_shape=(1,))(filtered_return)

returns_output = LSTM(units=1)(filtered_return)
lstm_return = Model(inputs=return_inputs, outputs=returns_output)
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (1, 1, 1, 1)

Comment: Your error is self explanatory you are passing a mishaped tensor as your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiply(x):
    return  tf.keras.layers.multiply(
        [tf.slice(x, [0, 0], [-1, 1]), tf.slice(x, [0, 1], [-1, 1])]
    )
```

The column and row were inverted when slicing the input, which messed up the dimension.